# Getting a fatal error for a set method

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

So I am writing a big program for school that simulates a gradebook. Ive been at this for days as to why it is randomly giving me runtime errors whenever I create a new course. The weird thing is it is only sometimes. Sometimes it works with flying colors and sometimes not. The Error code is Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3002)
and I get that error when I am assigning user input to a member of an array of course classes. The code will probably do me more justice.

Here is the definition of the classes I will comment the lines that are frequent in giving this error. The main one giving the error is in the course class.

```
//
//  Classes.hpp
//  Hw2
//
//  Created by Devin Tripp on 2/28/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Devin Tripp. All rights reserved.
//


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


#define CHUNKSIZE 2

class Student {
private:
    int stud_id;
    string name;
public:
    void setId(int id) { stud_id = id;}
    int getId() { return stud_id;}
    void setName(string n) { name = n; } // I recieve an error here sometimes
    string getName() { return name;}
};

class Students {
public:
    Students() {stud_cnt = 0; stud_cap = CHUNKSIZE; studs = new Student[CHUNKSIZE];}
    ~Students() { delete [] studs;}
    void addStudent();
    void printStudents();
    int getstud_cap();
    Student* getStuds();
    void storeStuds();
    void loadStuds();
private:
    int stud_cnt;
    int stud_cap;
    Student *studs;
};

class Course {
private:
    int course_id;
    string course_name;
public:
    void setID(int id) {course_id = id;}
    int getID() { return course_id;}
    void setCourseName(string name) { course_name = name;} // Recieve error here // still getting this error here with new changes
    string getCourseName() { return course_name;}
};

class Courses {
public:
    Courses() {course_cnt = 0; course_cap = CHUNKSIZE; course_list = new Course[CHUNKSIZE]; for (int i = 0; i < course_cap; i++){
    course_list[i].setID(-1);
    course_list[i].setCourseName("");                 //This still produces the same error
}}
    ~Courses() { delete [] course_list;}
    void addCourse();
    void printCourses();
    int getCourseCnt() {return course_cnt;}
    int getCourseCap() {return course_cap;}
    Course *getCourseList() {return course_list;}
    void loadCourses();
    void storeCourses();

private:
    int course_cnt;
    int course_cap;
    Course *course_list;

};


class Enrollment {
public:
    int getEnId() {return en_ID;}
    int getCourse_ID() {return course_ID;}
    string getCName() {return courseName;}
    string getSName() {return studentsNames;}
    int getStudID() {return studs_ID;}
    void setEnID(int id) { en_ID = id; }
    void setCourse_ID(int id) {course_ID = id;}
    void setCName(string name) { courseName = name; } // Recieve error here sometimes
    void setSname(string name) { studentsNames = name; }
    void setStudID(int id) {studs_ID = id;}
    void setGrades(int grade, int num) { grades[num] =  grade;}


private:
    int en_ID;
    int course_ID;
    string courseName;
    int studs_ID;
    string studentsNames;
    int change_this;
    int grades[9];



};

class Enrollments {
public:
    Enrollments() {enroll_cnt = 0; enroll_cap = CHUNKSIZE; enroll_list = new Enrollment[CHUNKSIZE];}
    ~Enrollments() { delete [] enroll_list;}
    void addEnrollment(Students s, Student *studs, Courses c, Course *cList);
    void printCourseStudent();
    void getAverage();
    void GetletterGrade();
    void addGradesToCourse();

    void loadEnrollments();
    void saveEnrollments();

private:
    int enroll_cnt;
    int enroll_cap;
    Enrollment *enroll_list;
};
```

This is all of the functions for the classes. The store and load functions started causing these problems when I added them in so maybe its something in the functions. I think it has to do with a string because it only has this error on the functions that set a string.

```
//
//  Classes.cpp
//  Hw2
//
//  Created by Devin Tripp on 2/28/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Devin Tripp. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "Classes.hpp"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int Students::getstud_cap() {
    return stud_cap;
}

void Students::addStudent() {
    int id;
    string temp;

    if (stud_cnt == stud_cap) {
        Student *temp;
        temp = new Student[stud_cap + CHUNKSIZE];
        for (int i = 0;i < stud_cnt; i++) {
            temp[i] = studs[i];
        }

        delete [] studs;
        stud_cap += CHUNKSIZE;
        studs = temp;

    }

    printf("Enter a new student ID: ");
    cin >> id; cin.ignore();
    printf("Enter Name: ");
    cin >> temp; cin.ignore();
    cout << "Got data " << temp << endl;

    studs[stud_cnt].setId(id); cout << "Set ID" << endl;
    studs[stud_cnt].setName(temp); cout << "Set Name" << endl;
    stud_cnt += 1; cout << "inc stud count" << endl;




}

void Students::printStudents() {

    for (int i = 0; i < stud_cap; i++)  {

        cout << studs[i].getName() << " " << studs[i].getId() << endl;
    }

}

void Courses::addCourse() {
    int id;
    string name;


    if (course_cnt == course_cap) {
        // increase the size of the array

        Course *temp;
        temp = new Course[course_cap + CHUNKSIZE];

        for(int i =0; i < course_cnt; i++){
            temp[i] = course_list[i];
        }
        delete [] course_list;
        course_cap += CHUNKSIZE;
        course_list = temp;
    }

    printf("Whats the Course ID?: ");
    cin >> id; cin.ignore();
    printf("Enter the Name of The Course: ");
    cin >> name; cin.ignore();
    cout << " Got data " << name << endl;

    if (name == "") {
        cin >> name;
    }



    course_list[course_cnt].setID(id);
    course_list[course_cnt].setCourseName(name);


    course_cnt += 1;
}

void Courses::printCourses() {

    for( int i = 0; i < course_cap; i++)
        cout << course_list[i].getID() << endl;
}

Student* Students::getStuds(){
    return studs;
}


void Enrollments::addEnrollment(Students s, Student *studs, Courses c, Course *cList) {
    s.printStudents();
    int id;
    int courseNum;
    int tempI = -1;
    int tempITwo = -1;

    /*Check if you need to alloc more memory to the array. */


    if (enroll_cnt == enroll_cap){
        // alloc more space chunksize has been reached
        // create temp to hold the previous array
        Enrollment *temp;
        temp = new Enrollment[enroll_cap + CHUNKSIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < enroll_cap; i++){
            temp[i] = enroll_list[i];
        }

        delete [] enroll_list;

        enroll_list += CHUNKSIZE;
        enroll_list = temp;
    }


    /* Find the student and the course */
    cout << "Type the students id: " << endl;
    cin >> id; cin.ignore();


    // loop through to find if the user typed in a number that matches the student id
    for (int i = 0; i < s.getstud_cap(); i++) {
         if(id == studs[i].getId()) {
             //save the i
             tempI = i;
         }
    }

    // check if it found the id or if the user typed in a wrong one
    if (tempI != -1){
        c.printCourses();
        cout << "Type the course number: " << endl;
        cin >> courseNum; cin.ignore();

        // check where in the array the id for the course is

        for(int i = 0; i < c.getCourseCap(); i++){
            if(courseNum == cList[i].getID()){
                tempITwo = i;
            }
        }


        // save the enrollment
        if (tempITwo != -1){
            enroll_list[enroll_cnt].setCName(cList[tempITwo].getCourseName());
            enroll_list[enroll_cnt].setCourse_ID(cList[tempITwo].getID());
            enroll_list[enroll_cnt].setSname(studs[tempI].getName());
            enroll_list[enroll_cnt].setStudID(studs[tempI].getId());
            enroll_list[enroll_cnt].setEnID(studs[tempI].getId() + cList[tempITwo].getID());

        } else {
            //wrong courseID
            cout << "You typed in an invalid course ID" << endl;
        }
    } else {
        //wrong student id
        cout << "You typed an invalid Student ID" << endl;
    }


    enroll_cnt += 1;
}


void Enrollments::printCourseStudent(){

    for (int i = 0; i < enroll_cap; i++) {

        cout << "Enrollment ID: " << enroll_list[i].getEnId() << " Course: " << enroll_list[i].getCName() << " Course ID: " << enroll_list[i].getCourse_ID() << " Student Name: " << enroll_list[i].getSName() << " Student ID: " << enroll_list[i].getStudID() << endl;
    }



}

void Enrollments::addGradesToCourse() {
    printCourseStudent();
    int id, count = 0, grade, tempI = -1;
    cout << "Type the enrollment ID: " << endl;
    cin >> id; cin.ignore();
    for(int i = 0; i < enroll_cap; i++){
        if (id == enroll_list[i].getEnId()) {
            tempI = i;

        }
    }

    if (tempI != -1){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            cout << "Enter grade " << count + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> grade; cin.ignore();

            enroll_list[tempI].setGrades(grade, count);
            count++;
        }

    }


}


void Courses::loadCourses(){

    ifstream fin;
    int id;
    string name;
    fin.open("/Users/devintripp/Desktop/swift projects/Hw2/Hw2/courses.dat");
    fin >> course_cnt; fin.ignore();
    course_list = new Course[course_cnt];

    for ( int i=0; i < course_cnt; i++) {

        fin >> id >> name;
        course_list[i] .setCourseName(name);
        course_list[i].setID(id);
    }
    fin.close();

}

void Courses::storeCourses() {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("/Users/devintripp/Desktop/swift projects/Hw2/Hw2/courses.dat");
    fout << course_cnt << endl;
    for ( int i=0; i < course_cnt; i++) {

        fout << course_list[i].getID() << " " <<  course_list[i].getCourseName() << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}

void Students::loadStuds(){

    ifstream fin;
    int id;
    string name;
    fin.open("/Users/devintripp/Desktop/swift projects/Hw2/Hw2/students.dat");
    fin >> stud_cnt; fin.ignore();
    studs = new Student[stud_cnt];

    for ( int i=0; i < stud_cnt; i++) {

        fin >> id >> name;
        studs[i].setName(name);
        studs[i].setId(id);
    }
    fin.close();

}

void Students::storeStuds() {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("/Users/devintripp/Desktop/swift projects/Hw2/Hw2/students.dat");
    fout << stud_cnt << endl;
    for ( int i=0; i < stud_cnt; i++) {
        fout << studs[i].getId() << " " <<  studs[i].getName() << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}

void Enrollments::loadEnrollments(){

    ifstream fin;
    int eid, sid, cid;
    string cname, sname;
    fin.open("/Users/devintripp/Desktop/swift projects/Hw2/Hw2/enrollments.dat");
    fin >> enroll_cnt; fin.ignore();
    enroll_list = new Enrollment[enroll_cnt];

    for ( int i=0; i < enroll_cnt; i++) {

        fin >> eid >> cname >> sname >> sid >> cid;
        enroll_list[i].setEnID(eid);
        enroll_list[i].setCourse_ID(cid);
        enroll_list[i].setCName(cname);
        enroll_list[i].setSname(sname);
        enroll_list[i].setStudID(sid);
    }
    fin.close();

}

void Enrollments::saveEnrollments() {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("/Users/devintripp/Desktop/swift projects/Hw2/Hw2/enrollments.dat");
    fout << enroll_cnt << endl;
    for ( int i=0; i < enroll_cnt; i++) {
        fout << enroll_list[i].getEnId() << " " <<  enroll_list[i].getCourse_ID() <<  " " << enroll_list[i].getCName() << " " << enroll_list[i].getSName() << " " << enroll_list[i].getStudID();
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

And lastly I have the main method. It prompts the user for input and runs all the functions that were created in classes.cpp.

If you are gonna test the code you should probably change the store and load functions to your own path on your machine.

```
//
//  Devin Shawn Tripp
//  Student ID: 11199100
//  CSCE 1040!
//  Hw2
//
//  Created by Devin Tripp on 2/26/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Devin Tripp. All rights reserved.
//


// notes for tomorrow figure out how to add it to a file that I will create 
// 6 classes - main is not a class

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "Classes.hpp"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


void loadData();
void save();

/* Declare global Objects */
Students stud;
Courses co;
Enrollments e;


int main() {
    /* Declare Variables */
    int choice = 0;


    /* Create Menu */
    while (choice != 7) {
        loadData();
        printf("What do you want to do: \n");
        printf("1: Add new Course \n2: Add New Student \n3: Print Students \n4: Save \n5: Add Enrollment \n6: Add Grades to a Course\n7: Quit \n");

        cin >> choice;


        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                // Add a course
                co.addCourse();
                break;
            case 2:
                //Add Students
                stud.addStudent();
                break;
            case 3:
                // Print students
                stud.printStudents();
                break;
            case 4:
                //do something
                //stud.save();
                break;
            case 5:
                //do something
                e.addEnrollment(stud, stud.getStuds(), co, co.getCourseList());
                break;
            case 6:
                //do something
                e.addGradesToCourse();
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }


        save();
    }

    return 0;
}


void loadData(){
    stud.loadStuds();
    co.loadCourses();
    e.loadEnrollments();
}

void save() {
    stud.storeStuds();
    co.storeCourses();
    e.saveEnrollments();
}
```

Comment: Not your solution but your array enlargement method is very odd. Normally you would use `realloc` to dynamically enlarge the array as required.

Comment: Are you talking about where I create a temp array to store the old arrays data then delete the old array then assign temp to the new array?

Comment: Yes, but I have also noted your problem and I am providing an answer :)

Comment: Thats the way our instructor did it. @Geoffrey

Comment: Oh ok Thanks! @Geoffrey

Comment: Quit using `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]`. Use standard containers like `std::vector`.  If the instructor insists otherwise, he or she needs to be re-initialized.

Comment: Can you use standard containers, or must you use new[] and delete[]?

Comment: Too many notes. Trim it down to the bare essentials. Post a [MCVE], all in one piece, not main.cpp, Classes.hpp, etc...

Comment: If you cannot use `std::vector` for an assignment like this you should write one. Gets all of the messy array management and resize logic into one place.

Comment: The real beauty of the MCVE ([mcve]) is it forces you to examine and reexamine your code as you chop out that which isn't bug. Ultimately you wind up with a program that is bug, all bug, and nothing but bug, and usually long before you reach that point you see the bug yourself and can fix it. If you haven't started on a MCVE, you haven't really started debugging yet.

Comment: An example MCVE for your program: https://ideone.com/t6FRJC

Comment: I would love to but i have almost no idea what I am doing half the time with c++. I really don't know where to start with that kind of error. If it was a segmentation fault yeah i wouldn't even need to post a question, but i could do it yourway, but I have no idea where to even look i have never seen such a simple concept like a set method give me an error. Its mind boggling. It shouldn't give me an error. From what I know the array has values. I then assign different values to the name and the id i can see that the cins are taking these values because they print them back out but the set me

Comment: thod is not working, because it is not setting the array with the values provided by the cin sooooooo. I have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: Alright, let's walk through the numbers: `int grades[9];` is valid for indexes 0 through 8. This index is being supplied by a loop that ranges 0 through 9. When that index hits 9, bad smurf happens. This is exactly what happens in `addGradesToCourse`. `setGrades` writes to the 9 element `grades` array and is called in a 10 iteration for loop. Could be more errors in there, but that's the one that jumped out at me. That's another reason for the MCVE. It allows you to isolate and fix one and only one bug in a potential sea of bugs.

Comment: see addGradesToCourse works perfect no errors

Comment: 0 through 9 is 10 index's the for loop goes from zero to 1 less than 10 which happens to be the exact number for grades[9]

Comment: 1 less than 10 is 9. The last valid index for `grades` is 8. You access `grades[9]` and the program breaks. How it breaks is undefined. It might look like it's working, but it's not.

Comment: 0 - 9 is 10 values

Comment: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: I don't get an array is out of bounds error or a segmentation fault because memory wasn't allocated so no that function is fine

Answer (score -1):

The objects have been allocated space, but you have not called their constructors, as such they have not been initialized, for example:

```
A* arrayOfAs = new A[5]; //Allocate a block of memory for 5 objects
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    //initialize an object in memory address provided by the pointer
    new (&arrayOfAs[i]) A();
}
```

I however would suggest you avoid this usage entirely and use `std::vector` as it wraps all this up including array enlargement.

ie:

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<Student*> Students;
Students studs;

// add an item
Student * student = new Student();
studs.push_back(student);

// remove an item
Student * student = studs.pop_front();
delete student;

// iterate the items
for(Students::iterator it = studs.begin(); it != studs.end(); ++it)
{
  Student * student = *it;
  student->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Operator `new[]` calls the default constructor on all elements of the new array.  So the placement `new` loop at the top of your answer will leak memory.  Beginners should not even be messing with `new[]` and `delete[]` at all.

Comment: so would I initialize them in the class definition

Comment: I don't know what "them" are. But let's not discuss it in the comments here.  I'll post an answer.  Can you use standard containers, or must you use `new[]` and `delete[]`?

Comment: I must use new and delete

Comment: @jiveDadson I updated the courses class to try and initialize the array like the first answer said to do,  but it still gives me the same error on the same line.]

Comment: Not surprised atoll.

Comment: @JiveDadson Any fixes?